# getAt operator mutating list

Tags: groovy

The following code:

```
def a = [4,10,6].iterator().sort();
println a[1];
println a[1];
```

Produces the following output:

```
6
null
```

Bizarrely it seems like `a[1]` is mutating the list. Where is this documented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should rather be

```
def a = [4,10,6].sort();
println a[1];
println a[1];
```

without `iterator()`!

Then it produces what you expects

```
6
6
```

**It is not mutating anything at all!** Result of `[...].iterator().sort()` is of type `java.util.ArrayList$ListItr` and than you use it with index 1 (method `getAt()` is called at `Iterator`) so you are shifting iterator by 2 elements and iterator is at last position. Then you do it again and trying to read item from last + 1 position, so it is returning `null`.

Documentation of [`Iterator.getAt()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Iterator.html#getAt%28int%29).